# \usepackage's phantom \ifnum

Tags: package-writing, datetime

So I'm trying my hand at creating some packages (on [WriteLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/), because my Surface can't run TeX<sup>1</sup>), and have run into a rather fascinating problem. My packages just won't load; they complain about `\ifnum` instead. Here's a minimal test case:

#### test.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994-06-01]
\ProvidesPackage{test}[2014-08-04 Hello, World!]
\endinput
```

#### main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{LaTeX Testing}
\usepackage{test}

\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

#### Compile error

```
Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   -
l.4
```

And I'm thinking, *when did* `\ifnum` *come into this?!* (The error occurs on the 'token' after `\usepackage`, whether that's a newline or a `\show` or whatever else.) There's plenty on the internet about `\ifnum` errors, but nothing on just after `\usepackage`. I have no idea where to even *start* debugging this, and my options are rather limited due to being stuck with an online service... Some help?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Surface RT is a pain sometimes. I do have a proper machine, with LaTeX on it; however, it's not quite as portable, and therefore isn't on hand at the moment.</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The date specification has to be of the format `YYYY/MM/DD` and not `YYYY-MM-DD`. The following minimal example works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{test}[2014/08/04 Hello, World!]
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}
\title{LaTeX Testing}
\usepackage{test}

\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

Comment: *\*double facepalm\**